# Application not published in G Suite marketplace

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store, google-workspace

We have an application published in G Suite marketplace and it  has suddenly disappeared.

We guess the problem is related with the [migration from Chrome webstore](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html), but we have updated the manifest following the steps in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing) and the application is still not listed in any of them. However, we cannot find the app by url in G Suite marketplace but we can find it by url in Chrome webstore, what seems pretty strange.

Google Marketplace SDK is enabled and configured in Google Cloud Platform.

I read in the documentation that "*Chrome Apps must use manifest version 2*", so I don't know if we need to set this to version 1 for G Suite applications.

We are using the same manifest as the documentation, but including "GOOGLE_DRIVE" in the container:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Welcome Aboard",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "description": "a plain text description",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icons/128x128-icon.png",
    "16": "icons/16x16-icon.png"
  },
  "container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE","GOOGLE_DRIVE"],
  "api_console_project_id": "428464274542",
  "app" : {
    "launch" : {
      "web_url" : "http://www.example.com/morepath/"
    }
  }
}
```

Are we missing something?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. We guess the manifest was old and needed to be reuploaded, after that it's just a matter of time because Google needs to validate it.

Anyway we created a support ticket for Google and they didn't mention anything about that. In fact they didn't clarify what was the problem. Maybe they have accelerated the validation process after we contacted them.

JV: Adding link to Google Support Thread
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71747494

Answer (score 0):

[From Chrome Apps to the Web](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html)

**Update on December 5, 2017**:

> Chrome Apps will be removed from Chrome Web Store search & browse
>   functions in mid-December 2017. Existing apps will continue to work
>   and receive updates.  The Chrome browser will continue to load
>   packaged and hosted apps on Windows, Mac, and Linux beyond the
>   previously announced deprecation timeline. Another update will be
>   posted here when a new date for the Chrome Apps EOL on Windows, Mac,
>   and Linux has been finalized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @noogui. I found that too and it's right, our application was searchable in Chrome webstore and G Suite marketplace and now it's not searchable in Chrome webstore (this is correct) but it has disappeared from G Suite Marketplace (this is not correct). The application is a G Suite app, not a Chrome extension. It seems that Google has made some changes in marketplace and we need to contact directly with them.